# ng-pattern for letters and hyphens

Tags: angularjs, regex

```
<input name="name" type="text" ng-maxlength="100" placeholder="name" required ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s\-]*$/">
```

I tried the above but it did not accept hyphens. How can I write it?

example input: "joseph-fourier" without quotes

Comment: That  is weird, show more of your relevent code.

Comment: Show given input string.

Comment: @revo i added an example input string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sharing a sample code Please check :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    angular.module('AppExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.regex = '^[a-zA-Z\-]*$';  // Regex for String with hyphens
      }]);
  </script>
  <body ng-app="AppExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form name="form">
      
      <label for="input">Enter name (hyphens allowed)</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="model" id="input" name="input" ng-pattern="{{regex}}" />
      Is input valid = <code>{{form.input.$valid}}</code><br>
  </div>
</body>
  </html>
```

[image: Valid String Output]